# x64 asm strange behavior

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

Can someone help me with understanding x64 asm behaviour? I cant find any kind of documentation for that.

So, basically, we have:

- x64 register `RAX`.
- x32 register `EAX`.
- x16 register `AX`.
- x8 register `AL`.

and now code:

```
mov rax, -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
add al, 1
```

result will be 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00 (correct, `al` register overflow, but we change only `AL` 1 byte)

```
mov rax, -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
add ax, 1
```

result will be 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF0000 (correct, `ax` register overflow, but we change only `AX` 2 bytes)

```
mov rax, -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
add eax, 1
```

result will be 0x0000000000000000 (wtf?, `eax` register overflow, but result change all 8 bytes instead of 4. Why it is 0x0000000000000000 but not 0xFFFFFFFF00000000)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register

Comment: note that `add eax, 0` will also clear the most-significant half of `RAX`.

Comment: Btw there are only half as many bytes than you've written, `al` is 1 byte, `ax` is two bytes, etc.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. My misstake, ofc they 1-2-4-8 bytes

Answer (score 1):

> 32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit
>   result in the destination general-purpose register.

Thats is. Thanks!

```
mov rax, 0x6666666666666666
add eax, 1
```

result confirm this and will be 0x0000000066666667